# Coffescript not compiling in rails app. Says syntax error - unexpected indentation

Tags: coffeescript

I'm new to coffeescript and I'm not sure what is wrong with my syntax. I want to add an error message if either the date or time field is empty upon clicking the update button. Here is my code.

```
$.add_error = (field, message) ->
  unless field.hasClass('input-error')
    field.after('<span class="input-error-message">' + message + '</span>')
  field.addClass('input-error')

$.remove_error = (field) ->
  field.removeClass('input-error')
  field.parent().find('.input-error-message').remove()

$('.btn.update_schedule').click ->
  date = $('#date')
  time = $('#time')
  if (date.val() && !time.val()) || (!date.val() && time.val())
    if !time.val()
      $.add_error(repeat_count, 'Please select both a date and time')
      false
    else !date.val()
      $.add_error(repeat_date, 'Please select both a date and time')
      false
    else
      $.remove_error(time) || $.remove_error(date)
```

I'm unable to compile this code because it says there's an unexpected indentation but I don't see it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by removing everything from the file - add each step one by one and try compiling it... until it gives you the syntax error. The last thing you added is the line with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last block `$('.btn.update_schedule').click ->`, there is an

```
 if ... else ... else ...
```

that is basically non-sense.

It seems that should be instead an

```
if ... else if ... else ...
```

This seems the correct version:

```
$('.btn.update_schedule').click ->
  date = $('#date')
  time = $('#time')
  if (date.val() && !time.val()) || (!date.val() && time.val())
    if !time.val()
      $.add_error(repeat_count, 'Please select both a date and time')
      false
    else if !date.val()
      $.add_error(repeat_date, 'Please select both a date and time')
      false
    else
      $.remove_error(time) || $.remove_error(date)
```